# Bootstrap-Vue - input with HTML

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I am trying to put some HTML (even `<b>` tags) in [Bootstrap-Vue `Input`](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-input/#datalist-support) fields.

```
    <template>
      <b-form-input></b-form-input>
      <datalist id="my-list-id">
        <option v-for="size in sizes">{{ size }}</option>
      </datalist>
    </template>

...
new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    data: {
        sizes: ['Manual Option', '<b>bold</b>first', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra Large'],
```

[image]

However, I was unable to find out how to use the HTML members, instead of plain-text members in the selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not recommended due to possible Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks, you can use `v-html` to place HTML content inside elements (just make sure it is content that **you** provide and **not** users)

```html
  <template>
    <div>
      <b-form-input list="my-list-id"></b-form-input>
      <datalist id="my-list-id">
        <option v-for="size in sizes" v-html="size"></option>
      </datalist>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Note that the HTML will not show in the `<b-form-input>`, as native `<input>` elements do not support HTML content.

Comment: Well, so actually it's not possible to have it as other "combo box" extensions offer to have i.e. image + text in the chosen input field.

Comment: many thanks for noting that to me. As I've read about Vulnerabilities, and I wouldnt directly render any user-content without sanitization from backend.